# Is there a standard benchmark data set for "Homomorphic Encryption" implementations?

Tags: homomorphic-encryption

Both in terms of statistical analysis (mean/variance, histograms, contingency tables, etc) and machine learning data sets. The question has also been asked [here](https://www.quora.com/Is-there-a-standard-benchmark-data-set-for-Homomorphic-Encryption-implementations-like-the-ones-for-database-TPC-C).

Comment: This is hard in practice, one has to talk about many parameters and these changes over time due to new foundings. Usually you can find some results in implementations.